# mypy: error: Module "multiprocessing.managers" has no attribute "EventProxy" [attr-defined]

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I have a method which takes a `multiprocessing.Manager().Event()`, for the purposes of gracefully stopping my app.

When I run mypy against it, it complains that it's not a valid type:

```
error: Module "multiprocessing.managers" has no attribute "EventProxy" [attr-defined]
```

Code:

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import EventProxy

class App:
    def run(self, stop_event: EventProxy):
        ...

with Manager() as manager:
    stop_event = manager.Event()
    a = App()
    a.run(stop_event)
```

I used the type `EventProxy` because when I checked the `type()` of the `multiprocessing.Manager().Event()` it said it was a `multiprocessing.managers.EventProxy`.

How can I type hint this method so that mypy won't complain?

Versions:

```
Python          3.9.14
mypy            0.991
mypy-extensions 0.4.3
```

Comment: Maybe something like `from multiprocessing.synchronize import Event as EventType`? `multiprocessing.Event` is actually a bound method that returns `multiprocessing.synchronize.Event` as shown [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/multiprocessing/context.py#L90).

Comment: It seems for `multiprocessing.Manager().Event()` you should type hint with `threading.Event`. Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.Event

Comment: That seems to have silenced mypy. I can't say I understand it though... the type() of the stop_event didn't mention SyncManager at all - rather it mentioned EventProxy. Could you post an answer and I'll mark it as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Manager):
`multiprocessing.Manager()` Returns a started `SyncManager` object.

If we check the docs for [`SyncManager.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.Event) we see that it returns `threading.Event`.

So in summary:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
from threading import Event

class App:
    def run(self, stop_event: Event) -> None:
        print('Hello')

with Manager() as manager:
    stop_event = manager.Event()
    a = App()
    a.run(stop_event)
```